# Restrict forward slash at the end of URL

Tags: javascript

I have used the following regex to put the validation in my URL:

```
/^(((ht|f){1}((tp|tps):[/][/]){1})|((www.){1}))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+$/;
```

I want to restrict forward slash also from the last of URL.
Ex: `https://abc.python/com/`

So, the last slash after `com` should not be allowed.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Note that your regexp is not very accurate, try `wwwhat??` or `http://####`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
const test = (val) => console.log(/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+(?<!\/)$/g.test(val), val);

test("http://test.com/test")
test("https://test.com/test/com/")
test("https://test.com/test/com")
test("www.test.com")
test("test.com/")
```

Comment: I am getting error with this regular expression -> Parsing error: Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+(?<!\/)$/: Invalid group

Comment: You've removed some backslashes, copy and paste the exact same regex and it will work!

Comment: No, i haven't removed any. I have copy pasted the same regex. And it is working in my local also. But while generating the bundle in nodejs I am getting above error. May be it's because javascript doesn't support lookbehind !

Comment: It does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions

Comment: But i am getting error while generating bundle with same regex !